# Pickle high scores and then print

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm trying to pickle high scores and then print them.

In the actual program, score is acquired from a simple trivia game.

```
score = 10
name = input("Name: ")
scores = [name, score]
high_scores = open("high_scores.dat", "ab")
pickle.dump(scores, high_scores)
high_scores.close()

high_scoresR = open("high_scores.dat", "rb")
results = pickle.load(high_scoresR)
print(results)
high_scores.close()
```

The program prints only the first high score entered, it doesn't matter how many scores I try to dump to it. Example:

```
['Jason', 10]
```

I am guessing I don't understand something quite basic, so I would highly appreciate a informative and clear explanation.

Comment: Although not an answer to the question in hand, might I recommend for the future you use [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).  It's got cool stuff for doing this and will probably make your life easier.

Comment: if you `dump` 5 times to the file, then you will need to do `load` 5 times.  One `load` for every `dump`.

Comment: or you could make a high scores dict, and `dump` the dict all at once.  then, you'd only need the one `load`.

Comment: I have to agree with the other comments, are you trying to learn `pickle` or you're more interested in storing data?

Comment: I am trying to learn pickle, and I can't dump the entire dictionary/list all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `'wb'` mode to write multiple pickles to a file, and if you need to reopen it for one ore more additional `dump`, then you should use append mode (`'a'`, not `'w'`).  Here I write multiple entries using `'wb'`, and then later add one entry using `'ab'`.

```
>>> scores = dict(Travis=100, Polly=125, Guido=69)
>>> import pickle                               
>>> with open('scores.pkl', 'wb') as highscores:
...   for name,score in scores.items(): 
...     pickle.dump((name,score)), highscores)
... 
>>> with open('scores.pkl', 'ab') as highscores:
...   pickle.dump(scores, highscores)
... 
>>> with open('scores.pkl', 'rb') as highscores:
...   a = pickle.load(highscores)
...   b = pickle.load(highscores)
...   c = pickle.load(highscores)
...   d = pickle.load(highscores)
... 
>>> a
('Travis', 100)
>>> b
('Polly', 125)
>>> c
('Guido', 69)
>>> d
{'Polly': 125, 'Travis': 100, 'Guido': 69}
>>>
```

And if you have a lot of data, so that you are worried about being able to `dump` and/or `load` all of your items at once, then you can use (one of my packages) `klepto`, which enables you to store large pickled data to a file, directory, or database… where you can seamlessly access one entry at a time.

```
>>> import klepto
>>> store = klepto.archives.dir_archive('high', serialized=True) 
>>> store.update(scores)
>>> store
dir_archive('high', {'Polly': 125, 'Guido': 69, 'Travis': 100}, cached=True)
>>> # dump all entries at once
>>> store.dump()
>>> # create a new empty archive proxy
>>> store2 = klepto.archives.dir_archive('high', serialized=True)
>>> store2 
dir_archive('high', {}, cached=True)
>>> # load one entry, as opposed to loading all entries
>>> store2.load('Guido')
>>> store2
dir_archive('high', {'Guido': 69}, cached=True)
>>> store2['Guido']
69
>>> # load everything else
>>> store2.load()
>>> store2
dir_archive('high', {'Polly': 125, 'Guido': 69, 'Travis': 100}, cached=True)
>>>
```

Comment: Many thanks, but (regarding the first code, w/o klepto) how can I print the whole file? I don't know the names of the keys I want to print.

Comment: @GalA.: if you have all `scores` as a `dict` (or a `list`, or some other single object), you can `dump` everything to a file with a single `dump`.  File mode `'wb'` will treat all files as new (destroying old entries), while `'ab'` will always append.  If you mean you want to "`print`" the whole file, you can read it as if it were a text file, and then `print` the file as a string.  But if you are just looking to `dump` everything, then use a single `dump` with `'wb'` -- note that, in that case, you will have to read all the scores in a single object on load.

Comment: Additionally. if you for some reason **can't** dump all the keys at once, **and** you **don't** know the names of the keys… you could just iterate over all the entries.  I'll edit for that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could read your file into a dictionary:

```
name = input('Enter name: ')
score = input('Enter score: ')

# write new entry to file
with open('highscores.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(name + ':' + score + '\n')

# read file into dict
with open('highscores.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
scores = dict(line.split(':') for line in lines)

for key, value in scores.items():
    print(key, value)
```

I didn't know you were trying to learn `pickle`, but maybe this helps someone else.

Comment: thanks, but I already did a similiar program for plain text files. Now I want to create one with pickled files, to learn and practice the subject.